# algorithm enumerating sequences

Tags: node.js, algorithm, sequence

I have an algorithmic problem.

Assume we have a sequence of labels like following

`E1 B1 B2 E2 B3 E3`

indexes don't have any meaning, I used them in order to distinguish between different B's and E's.

The task is enumerate all possible sequence of pairs BE that could be construct.

for example from the above example I can construct

```
B1 E2

B1 E3

B1 E2 B3 E3

B2 E2

B2 E3

B2 E2 B3 E3

B3 E3
```

I hope I found all of them,  the length of the sequence (the number of pairs) is not limited of course. Pairs are always B E, where B for begin, E for end.

The problem is I cannot come up with something generic.

Comment: I'd start by creating two new lists; one with the B's and the other with the E's.  Figuring out the algorithm after that should be trivial.

Comment: Going off @RobertHarvey's comment, you can create the lists by filtering your existing one via. 1st character match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think this should do the trick. It's certainly not optimized though.

```
var labels = ['E1', 'B1', 'B2', 'E2', 'B3', 'E3'];
var results = [];
var temp_results = [];
var i, j, index, new_item;

// Utility function to add an array inside an other array if it isn't in it yet.
function pushIfNotExists(container, insert) {
  var found = false;
  var i, different;
  container.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.length === insert.length) {
      different = false;
      for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i] !== insert[i]) {
          different = true;
        }
      }
      if (!different) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
  });

  if (!found) {
    container.push(insert);
  }
}

// This loops makes the basic (2 labels) sequences.
for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  if (labels[i].charAt(0) === 'B') {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < labels.length; j++) {
      if (labels[j].charAt(0) === 'E') {
        temp_results.push([labels[i], labels[j]]);
      }
    }
  }
}

// This loops combines the sequences
while (temp_results.length > results.length) {
  results = temp_results.slice(0);
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    index = labels.indexOf(results[i][results[i].length - 1]);
    for (j = index + 1; j < results.length; j++) {
      if (labels.indexOf(results[j][0]) > index) {
        new_item = results[i].concat(results[j]);
        if (temp_results.indexOf(new_item) === -1) {
          pushIfNotExists(temp_results, new_item);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some (incomplete) thoughts...

```
   E1 B1 B2 E2 B3 E3
pos 1  2  3  4  5  6

posB = indices of B  // 2, 3, 5
posE = indices of E  // 1, 4, 6

output = {}     

append_list_of_len_2():
    for i = 1 to len( posB ):
       j = first elem in posE greater than i
       for( ; j < len( posE ); j++ ):
           output.append( {i, j} )
```